# Black-body intensity curves for different temperatures [simple]

Tags: matlab

I have written a function that will calculate the intensity depending on temperature on wavelength. This is what the code looks like for the temperature 600 K:

```
function f=radiation(l,t)

l = linspace(0,10^-5,100); % The interval for the wavelength
a = 3.7415*10^(-16) ;      % constant
b = 0.014388;              % constant
t=600;                     % Setting the temperature to 600 K
f = a./(l.^5.*(exp(b./(l*t))-1)); 
plot(l,f)
```

Now I want to plot curves for different temperatures in the same window without having to repeat the code. How can I do this in a neat way?

Comment: You can pass multiple lineseries to `plot`, see the third input syntax in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). Alternatively, see: [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Comment: Scratch that, won't work. Use a loop over values of your temperature, then see @excaza's comment for plotting multiple instances (i.e. just make `f` a matrix with columns for different temperature)

Comment: Use [hold](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to keep the current plot. You may also wish to store all values of f using a multi-dimensional or cell array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way without having to loop over multiple temperatures:

```
l = linspace(0,10^-5,100); % The interval for the wavelength
a = 3.7415*10^(-16) ;      % constant
b = 0.014388;              % constant
t=[600,800,1000,1200];
figure;             
[t,l] = meshgrid(t,l);
f = a./(l.^5.*(exp(b./(l.*t))-1)); 
plot(l,f)
legend(num2str(t(1,:)'))
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

Comment: With the relevant documentation quote: `If one of X or Y is a vector and the other is a matrix, then the matrix must have dimensions such that one of its dimensions equals the vector length. If the number of matrix rows equals the vector length, then the plot function plots each matrix column versus the vector. If the number of matrix columns equals the vector length, then the function plots each matrix row versus the vector. If the matrix is square, then the function plots each column versus the vector.`